# How to return Observable.empty() if observable.filter().first() returns nothing?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

I have a function in RxJava which tries to find an Thing based on a condition, and if succeeds it transforms and returns it as an `Observable`. I want to return `Observable.empty()` if it is not able to find anything thus there is no first. 
I'm not sure about this, but I think if filter filters out every element in an `Observable` the result will be `Observable.empty()` anyway (without the `firstElement()`).

```
void Observable<Thing> transformFirst(Observable<Thing> things,Predicate<Thing> condition){
  return things
    .filter(condition)
    .firstElement()
    .map(firstThing ->{...do sg...})
}
```

**EDIT:**

My problem is that `firstElement()` returns a `Maybe<Thing>` and I do not know how to turn that into an `Observable.empty()` when the `filter(condition)` filters out everything (`condition` evaulates to false for every `thing`)

Comment: How is `things.filter(condition)` where the `condition` always evaluates to `false` different from `Observable.empty()`?

Comment: I don't think it is different, I believe it will be `Observable.empty()`. But when I do `things.filter(condition).firstElement()` it will return a `Maybe<Thing>` and I don't know how to turn that to an `Observable.empty()`

Comment: Why do you use `firstElement()` then ?

Comment: Because I want the algo to stop after the first match, I do not care about the rest of the items. This should make it slightly faster on large datasets.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `.first(condition)` then...

Comment: `Observable.empty()` is a constant empty source and is not the same as an arbitrary `Observable` filtered and ending up having no items. Why not keep working with `Maybe`, which indicates you may or may not have an item. At best you could convert it back to an `Observable` via `toObservable()`.

Comment: @akarnokd What is the type of an Observable fitlered and ending up having no items?  Or what is the result of that?

Comment: I thought [the signature](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#filter-io.reactivex.functions.Predicate-) is clear about it. Also just looking at an `Observable` instance won't tell you if it will emit any or no items at all.

Comment: Yeah I got confused, thank you for clearing up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add switchIfEmpty() as shown below,

```
return things
    .filter(condition)
    .switchIfEmpty(Observable.empty())
    .firstElement()
    .map(firstThing ->{...do sg...})
```

Comment: If I understand the [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#switchIfEmpty-io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.ObservableSource-) for `Observable#switchIfEmpty` correctly, then I doubt this is necessary and the correct answer. Because you are just creating a new empty signal given the source's empty signal. Leaving it out should not change the behavior.